# When the layout of my page gets jumbled after browsing the site, is the problem with WordPress or hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, css, theme

I've had problems with the loading view of my site. Initially everything looks OK but after clicking on other pages and coming back to the Home page the slider and other elements are not showing as they should and are a jumbled mess all over the page - other things like the menu bar and elements being the wrong colour.

Is this problem with WordPress - I use Enfold theme which is well supported and regularly updated - or is it a problem with my host and the site data not coming through quick enough?

Once things have gone wrong they don't resolve until I completely quit the browser - this has happened both on Safari and in Firefox.

Comment: "don't resolve until I completely quit the browser" -- What else have you tried?   Have you tried refreshing while holding down the shift key?   Have you tried clearing the browser cache?   Have you used the browser developer tools such as "inspect element" to try to find the issue?

Comment: Yes tried refreshing (also with shift key - but site visitor wouldn't do that). Didn't clear the browser cache, (but again the average site visitor do that?) - inspect element shows that the main page Avia slider is working although not all images are showing fully - then the Avia will disappear entirely for a cycle or two then reappear - although this isn't showing in inspect element

Comment: No, users wouldn't do those things, but those are things you need to try to diagnose problems like this.

Comment: Have you checked in the developer tools (F12 in chrome) and then the console tab for any errors?

Comment: Stephen - yes I understand those are the things I need to try in order to diagnose the problem, however my lack of experience is such that if did those things I wouldn't know what the result is telling me. If I clear the cache and the page works would that tell me that the error is with the host rather than WordPress or the theme? Also, even though I can see that the Avia slider is functioning in inspect element I don't understand enough to know if it's functioning correctly.

Comment: Steve - I'll try the F12 in chrome tonight and look for errors which may help.

Comment: Thanks both hopefully I'll be able to take your advise and get a bit further along with finding out the cause.

Comment: Stephen - I cleared the cache that didn't seem to make a difference to the odd performance behaviour - what should I take from that? What can I eliminate from list of the potential problems - was the cache clearing just to eliminate lack o fdisk space impeding the loading of the page? Thanks.